# Prevent NERD Tree from opening buffer on start

Tags: vim, nerdtree, janus

I'm using [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) for Vim customizations.

One thing that bothers me is that it opens [NERD Tree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) in a separate buffer on start. I don't want to disable NERD Tree completely. Just want to not get it opened on start.

Is there a way *without tweaking the internals* of Janus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out based on the [Janus configuration](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/nerdtree.vim#L8) mentioned by @romanl.

I had to add to `~/.vimrc.after`

```
augroup AuNERDTreeCmd
  autocmd!
augroup end
```

Answer (score -1):

Yet another "plugin distribution for Vim" user who chose to give complete control over his Vim configuration to someone else and has no idea how to change the default behaviour. Yeah, "easy" is so better than "hard".

This behaviour is probably defined in an `autocmd`, somewhere in your "janus" directory or whatever it uses to store its things. Maybe [here](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/blob/master/janus/vim/tools/janus/after/plugin/nerdtree.vim#L8).

You should probably take this as an opportunity to rethink your choice, drop Janus entirely and adopt a saner configuration strategy.

If you are the one adding/removing stuff to your `~/.vimrc` and installing plugins, you simply can't find yourself in such a situation.

Comment: I decided against building all configuration by my own for a good reason. The problem with most vim users is that everyone is using different settings that makes it pretty hard to do pair programming for example. As long as there is no need, I prefer using something more general.

Comment: And no, I didn't find any `autocmd` related to NERD Tree.

Comment: Did you follow the link in my answer? It sure looks like a NERDTree-related `autocmd` to me. How would janus help in any way? It's just someone else's configuration. If you can't deal with a pair's custom config what are the chances that he can deal with your janus based config either?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me so far.

Comment: Comment that line and the automatic nerdtree will be gone. Look around for other NERDTree-related stuff just in case.